# Dividing by zero without ArithmeticException

Tags: java, oop, if-statement, math, truthtable

When trying to write a truthtable I tried to figure out the algorithm, and I found one that works. However now I don't understand why it doesn't throw a ArithmeticException.

```
for(int i=0; i<Math.pow(2, numberOfInputs()); i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<numberOfInputs(); j++)
        {
            System.out.print("" + i/(int) Math.pow(2, j)%2 + "\t");

        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

When trying this with numberOfInputs() returning 2, I get:

```
Truthtable
0   0   
1   0   
0   1   
1   1
```

But I dont't understand how this can be since Math.pow(2, j)%2 will be =0 multiple times?!

Comment: Look up "Java operator precedence".

Comment: The code is equivalent to `(i/2^j) % 2`

Comment: stop using `Math.pow(2, j)`. Use `1 << j` instead

Answer (score 2):

It's because of the precedence, this is executed first: `i/(int) Math.pow(2, j)`, then modulo. The first expression is never a division by zero. More about it in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).